# How include a image in devexpress datagrid

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

How can set icon in Dev express data grid depending on the value returning from Database

Comment: Any suggestion how to do this with a Dev Express WinForms TreeList?  The call to e.RowHandle fails.  Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are the steps.

- Add an ImageCollection to your form/window and add some icons 16x16 to it.
- Add a column to the Grid for the icons.
- Set the column's fieldName to image (whatever
  you like).
- Set the column's UnboundType to Object.
- Add a repositoryItemPictureEdit to
  the column's columnEdit.

All the above can be done in the designer. Then do the following

```
private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column == colImage1 && e.IsGetData) {
        string someValueFromDatabase = (string)gridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, colOne);
        if (someValueFromDatabase == "a") {
            //Set an icon with index 0
            e.Value = imageCollection1.Images[0];
        } else {
            //Set an icon with index 1
            e.Value = imageCollection1.Images[1];
        }
    }
}
```

The key here is handling the [CustomUnboundColumnData](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) and the repositoryItemPictureEdit.

Comment: This explanation was so much more straightforward than what I found on the DevExpress site--thanks. DevExpress could use some writers like you.

Comment: I think that `imageCollection1.Images(0)` is `imageCollection1.Images[0]`

Comment: best solution that the DevExpress support team