# How include a image in devexpress datagrid with filtering (using AutoFilterRow)

Tags: c#, datagrid, devexpress

I read the thread [How include a image in devexpress datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291409/how-include-a-image-in-devexpress-datagrid) and it all works well. I miss just filtering the column with images using AutoFilterRow in the grid. When AutoFilterRow is included in the column with image is only written: "No image data".

Comment: Please add what you tried in this question while still keeping the reference to the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoFilterRow does not support filtering by columns with images. If you wish to filter values by this column, I suggest you use the ImageComboBoxEdit control as an in-place editor in this column.
If filtering by this column is not required and the [GridColumn.OptionsFilter.AllowAutoFilter](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumnFilter_AllowAutoFiltertopic) option is disabled, you can show a standard TextEdit in this column with any specific text via the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event.